# Loading Seaside 30 in Pharo 3 results in a MetacelloProjectSpecLoadError about ConfigurationOfOmniBrowser?

Tags: pharo, seaside

No version found for #stable of ConfigurationOfOmniBrowser?

Just downloaded Pharo 3 from here: http://files.pharo.org/platform/Pharo3.0-portable.zip

Opened an workspace and did this:

```
Gofer new
    squeaksource: 'MetacelloRepository';
    package: 'ConfigurationOfSeaside30';
    load.
(Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfSeaside30) load.
```

I get this error:
[image: No version found for #stable of ConfigurationOfOmniBrowser]

Comment: Is there a reason you use Pharo 3? The current stable version of Pharo is Pharo 4 and in some month it will be Pharo 5. In those version you can load Seaside3 via a catalog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... in Pharo, correct configuration is `Seaside3`... and it is not in MetacelloRepository since starting in Pharo3 we switched to a "per version" repo.

So, this code should do the work:

```
Gofer new
    smalltalkhubUser: 'Pharo' project: 'MetaRepoForPharo30';
    configurationOf: 'Seaside3';
    loadStable.
```